# MarkLogic 8 - XQuery using Document manage and checkout

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have tried the below mentioned xquery. If document is not managed I want to manage the document using a DLS query otherwise I want to checkout the document.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace dls = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls"  at "/MarkLogic/dls.xqy";

let $uri :="/root/189966_01.xml"

let $i := dls:document-is-managed($uri)

return 
  if ($i = fn:false())
  then 

    dls:document-manage($uri,  fn:false(),   "Baz is now a managed document") 

    (:  dls:document-checkout($uri, fn:true(), "updating doc", 3600) :)

  else if ($i = fn:true())
  then

      dls:document-checkout($uri, fn:true(), "updating doc", 3600) 

  else 

    "No action"
```

please correct me if anything is wrong on my side.

Answer (score 1):

The xquery looks fine. Just a restructuring of the above query -

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace dls = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls"  at "/MarkLogic/dls.xqy";    
let $uri :="/root/189966_01.xml"    
let $i := dls:document-is-managed($uri)    
return 
    if ($i = fn:false()) then     
        dls:document-manage($uri,  fn:false(),   "Baz is now a managed document")    
    else     
        if ($i = fn:true()) then    
            dls:document-checkout($uri, fn:true(), "updating doc", 3600)     
    else    
        ()
```

Comment: How can I checkout the document after managing it in the same transaction.
In the above example I tried calling `dls:document-checkout` after `dls:document-manage` but I am getting an error as `DLS-UNMANAGED` which means document is not managed. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot checkout and manage in the same transaction.  You can checkout in 2 independent transactions in the same request, managed by a parent transaction (as long as you do not hold any locks before or during.